# Why does Audio stop playing in app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio

I have a program that plays a sound every time the user does an action. But after some time none of the audio works.

Sample code :

```
public void bPressed(View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity.this, R.raw.audio);
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mp.release();` When you are done with MediaPlayer:

> As an example, consider the problems that could happen if you forgot to release the MediaPlayer when your activity is stopped, but create a new one when the activity starts again. As you may know, when the user changes the screen orientation (or changes the device configuration in another way), the system handles that by restarting the activity (by default), so you might quickly consume all of the system resources as the user rotates the device back and forth between portrait and landscape, because at each orientation change, you create a new MediaPlayer that you never release. (For more information about runtime restarts, see Handling Runtime Changes.)

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

add `mp.release();` for example in your `onStop()`

Comment: No this does not solve the problem , the sounds just stops when the app is running and I only allow portrait mode.